# Access 1st column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I access the first column in this dataframe? 
If I refer to it by the column name ('Group11...'), I get an error 'Not in index'.

[First Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od4ZG.jpg)

Comment: To improve your question, copy and paste the code in the post instead of using an image..

Answer (score 5):

What you are refering to is the index of the dataframe. So, if your dataframe is called `df`, you can access the index using `df.index`.

Otherwise, if you want to refer to the as a column, you need to turn it into a column before using [pandas.DataFrame.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

### reproducible example:

Here's a reproducible example showing the two methods of accessing the index:

```
from StringIO import StringIO 
import pandas as pd 

data = """Group11.Primary.Phrase|count|num_cat
CP|4|4
DA|1|1
FW|7|7
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep="|", index_col=0)
print("here's how the dataframe looks like") 
print(df.head())

print("here's how to access the index") 
print(df.index)

print("if you want to turn the index values into a list")
print(list(df.index))

print("you can also reset_index as a column and access it") 
df = df.reset_index()
print(df["Group11.Primary.Phrase"])
```

Running the above code, gives you the following output:

```
here's how the dataframe looks like
                        count  num_cat
Group11.Primary.Phrase                
CP                          4        4
DA                          1        1
FW                          7        7

here's how to access the index
Index([u'CP', u'DA', u'FW'], dtype='object', name=u'Group11.Primary.Phrase')

if you want to turn the index values into a list
['CP', 'DA', 'FW']

you can also reset_index as a column and access it
0    CP
1    DA
2    FW
Name: Group11.Primary.Phrase, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

iloc return data based on a numeric index, here all rows for the first (python 0-indexed) column.

```
df.iloc[:,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the index and then access column by the column name if you want to access it using column name. i.e

If you have a dataframe like

```
                        count  num_cat
Group11.Primary.Phrase                
CP                          4        4
DA                          1        1
FW                          7        7
```

Then after resetting index when you access the column by its name then

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['Group11.Primary.Phrase']
```

Output:

```
0    CP
1    DA
2    FW
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the docs: [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) In your case, you would index `df['Group11']`

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
               A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2000-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2000-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804

In [12]: df[['A', 'B']]
Out[12]: 
               A         B
2000-01-01 -0.282863  0.469112
2000-01-02 -0.173215  1.212112
2000-01-03 -2.104569 -0.861849
```